# How can I filter filenames based on their extension?

Tags: perl, list, filter

The following script stores all the files and directories in the array `@file_list`.

How do I only filter only files with the `.lt6` extension and none other than that?

```
opendir (CURRDIR, $localdir);
@file_list = grep !/^\.\.?$/, readdir CURRDIR;
print STDOUT "Found Files: @file_list\n";
```

cheers

Answer (score 9):

Try this:

```
grep(/\.lt6$/i, readdir(CURRDIR))
```

I've used it many times.  It works, although now I prefer to use [File::Next](http://search.cpan.org/dist/File-Next/) for this sort of thing.

Example:

```
use File::Next;

my $iter = File::Next::files( { file_filter => sub { /\.lt6$/ } }, $localdir )

while ( defined ( my $file = $iter->() ) ) {
    print $file, "\n";
}
```

Comment: Rather similar answers - case-insensitive vs not, and parentheses vs not parentheses.  :D

Comment: And we answered within one minute of each other.  Great minds think alike 8D.  Although in this case I guess I was the fastest gun in the west!

Comment: Yeah - I should know better than to edit the question before giving an answer :D

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget to `closedir()`.

Your `grep` should look for:

```
my(@file_list) = grep /\.lt6$/, readdir CURRDIR;
```

Assuming the rest of your syntax is approximately correct.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [File::Find::Rule](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc?File::Find::Rule);

```
use File::Find::Rule;

print "FOUND:\n    "
    , join( "\n    "
          , File::Find::Rule->file->name( '*.lt6' )->in( $path )
          )
    , "\n"
    ;
```

Comment: This has the extra feature of recursive descent. If you only want the files in the top-level directory, this is a mighty big gun to pull out for no extra benefit.

Comment: It's only as heavy as the scope of the list of files, which is unspecified from the description. It avoids the procedural open-loop-close structure, and I've never liked the separate syntax for opendir/closedir, anyway. It hardly seemed an improvement over sh's $(ls).

Answer (score 2):

```
my @file_list = glob "$localdir/*.lt6";
```

Answer (score 1):

```
opendir (CURRDIR, $localdir);
@file_list = grep m/\.lt6$/, readdir CURRDIR;
closedir CURRDIR;
print STDOUT "Found Files: @file_list\n";
```

Comment: You don't need to check for . and .. if you only pass through things ending in .lt6. :)

Answer (score 0):

And to add a little variety, you can also do stuff like this:

```
opendir(DIR, $path) || die qq([ERROR] Cannot opendir "$path" - $!\n);
my(@txt) = grep(m{\.txt$}, readdir DIR);
rewinddir DIR;
my(@lt6) = grep(m{\.lt6$}, readdir DIR);
rewinddir DIR;
my(@dirs) = grep(-d "$path/$_", readdir DIR);
closedir DIR;
```

And so on.

Answer (score -1):

Go to the command prompt

cd \

dir /s *.lt6 > mydir.txt